# TypeScript union key for Map

Tags: typescript

Please consider this code using a `string | number` union type as `Map` keys:

```js
type MyMap = Map<number | string, string>;

// ✅ Fine
const myMap: MyMap = new Map([
    [100, "number"]
]);

//  TS error 
const myMapErr: MyMap = new Map([
  [100, "number"],
  ["some", "string"],
]);
```

The error:

> Argument of type '([number, string] | [string, string])[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<readonly [number, string]>'.
> The types returned by 'Symbol.iterator.next(...)' are incompatible between these types.

Why is this failing? How can it be fixed (without losing type information)?

Comment: It's considered a TS bug, as per [ms/TS#39133](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39133). For now the workaround is to manually specify the type arguments to the `Map` constructor like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WzQOem) shows. See the linked q/a for more info.

Comment: This has been closed as duplicate, but I kindly ask to re-open.

Yes, both questions ultimately point to the same underlying problem. But users come to SO precisely because **they don't know the underlying problem yet**. I did search before asking and found nothing for the keywords that seemed relevant to me (typescript, map, union keys).

Also, the question in the duplicate is about inferred types, which is (again, for the 'end-user') quite different from explicitly stating types and trying to conform to them.

Comment: @panepeter The whole point of closing as duplicate is to not repeat information, and provide signposts to a (hopefully) canonical answer. The fact your question was closed as a duplicate is not to shame you or anything.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks for clarifying. I didn't (consciously at least) feel shamed, but I appreciate your words nonetheless. I do still think it's quite a mental stretch (for somebody coming from google, probably in a rush, attention span < 10s) to realize that the linked question contains the answer to this quesiton. But hey, I got my answer at least :D